# ID and firstName of persons who have sent a private message to another person who has the same firstName

Tags: sql, mysql, relational-database

The asterisked attributes in the relational database schema code below are primary keys.

The publicMessage entity stores the messages that were transmitted in virtually public place (i.e. a WhatsApp group).

The privateMessage entity stores the private messages users sent privately and individually one to each other.
pID1 represents the senders whereas pID2 represents the receiver.

```
person(**ID**, firstName, lastName, nickName)
follows(**pID1**, **pID2**)
publicMessage(**ID**, pID, date, text)
privateMessage(**ID**, pID1, pID2, date, text)
```

I would like to write an SQL query that lists the ID and firstName of persons who have sent a private message to another person who has the same firstName. The query should retrieve only the persons who sent a private message either to themselves or to other receivers who posses the same firstName.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID, p1.firstName
FROM person p1
JOIN privateMessage pm ON p1.ID = pm.pID1
JOIN person p2 ON pm.pID2 = p2.ID
WHERE p1.firstName = p2.firstName
OR pm.pID1 = pm.pID2;
```

I used the DISTINCT keyword to eliminate name repetitions.

I used the JOIN clause to connect the person table with the privateMessage table twice (as p1 and p2) based on the     sender (pID1) and receiver (pID2) IDs.

The WHERE clause ensures that I only include rows where the first names match between the sender (p1) and receiver (p2) or if the sender is sending a private message to themselves (pm.pID1 = pm.pID2).

What are mistakes in the query?

What is a more elegant/efficient code which retrieves more effectively?

Comment: The query is correct. You can leave out the `OR pm.pID1 = pm.pID2` part, as if user sends a message to himself/herself, the firstname will be the same both for the sender and the receiver.

Comment: Are names always going to be entered with a consistent case? Could you have first names of 'Cristi', 'cristi' and 'CRISTI' and, if so, should they all be treated as the same first name?

Comment: Please: Ask 1 question. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Use emphatic fonts sparingly. Clarity comes from clear phrasing & organization. Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't give. Don't number lines of code, a post can be edited by anyone at any time. Yes or no questions are seldom useful & seldom ask what the asker actually wants answered. It is not helpful to restate code in prose. We can read code. Explain why that code was written, in terms of the application/specification/interfaces, if it isn't obvious. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @NickW exactly. Quite frankly I didn't really factor in the uppercase implications. You made quite a good point. And I wouldn't know how to deal with that shortage and what exactly I should add/modify across my code.

Comment: Convert the first names to a consistent case - just pick upper or lower

Comment: @philipxy sir, you might have perceived the entire post utterly wrong if you are asking for technical and pragmatical motivations. 
Firstly, I saw necessary to break down the code and elaborate on its pieces for getting the readers familiar with my way of reasoning I employed when working out this problem.

Comment: This is a SQL repost slightly rephrased of recent post [Improving my solution for this Relational-Algebra query exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78050528/3404097) (See the original versions by clicking on 'edited'.) It repeats the problems from there. PS Yet again: Your final statement about the code add nothing to what the code says. You don't explain why that code would return the desired result. PS The goal for the query is an easily found faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Comment: @philipxy sir, you might have perceived the entire post utterly wrong if you are asking for technical and pragmatical motivations. 
Firstly, I saw necessary to break down the code and elaborate on its pieces for getting the readers familiar with my way of reasoning I employed when working out this problem AND judging it accordingly.
You made this kind of accusation though, apart from saying that I used x, y and z in a poor way you haven't been capable of clearly stating what's wrong with this post.
I did numbered the code just for anchoring references and comments in between.

Comment: @philipxy Not pretty sure that you would have made the clear distinction between an RA and SQL querying approach if you had put forward this kind of comment. 
I also saw this post, as I checked it out thoroughly just to see that the subjected problem is an open reference everybody could access if looking throughout this - https://db-book.com/.

How the problem repeats itself if the implied query language is radically different and the questions slightly vary?

Comment: I did not make any accusations & I stated a bunch of technical problems & site conventions. Without question the 2 posts are copies of the other or some original. --The queries are not for exactly the same thing but they use the same DB & have the same unhelpful prose form including a repeat of code in prose that does not say why that code would give that answer. Please act on the comments. I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I did pretty much the same way as you did without using distinct.  This is on PostgreSQL 15.

```
create table person(
    id INT generated always as identity primary key,
    firstName  varchar(12),
    lastName varchar(12),
    nickName varchar(12))
    ;

create table privateMessage(
    id INT generated always as identity primary key,
    sender_id integer, 
    receiver_id integer, 
    date date, 
    message_text varchar(32),
    constraint fk04
       foreign key(sender_id) references person(id),
    constraint fk05
       foreign key(receiver_id) references person(id)
    
    ) 
    ;
```

Create some people...

```
insert into person (firstName, lastName, nickName) values ('Alice', 'Smith', '');   /* pk 1 */
insert into person (firstName, lastName, nickName) values ('Bob', 'Jones', '');       /* pk 2 */
insert into person (firstName, lastName, nickName) values ('Alice', 'Young', '');     /* pk 3 */
```

Create a few messages:

```
insert into privateMessage (sender_id, receiver_id, message_text) values (1, 1, 'message text 1');
insert into privateMessage (sender_id, receiver_id, message_text) values (1, 2, 'message text 2');
insert into privateMessage (sender_id, receiver_id, message_text) values (1, 3, 'message text 3');
insert into privateMessage (sender_id, receiver_id, message_text) values (2, 1, 'message text 4');
```

Query the data:

```
select 
    p1.firstName || ' ' || p1.lastName as sender_name,
    p2.firstName || ' ' || p2.lastName as receiver_name,
    pm1.message_text as message_text
from
    person p1,
    person p2,
    privateMessage pm1
where
    p1.firstName = p2.firstName and
    pm1.sender_id = p1.id and
    pm1.receiver_id = p2.id
;
```

Results:

```
sender_name     receiver_name   message_text
Alice Smith     Alice Smith     message text 1
Alice Smith     Alice Young     message text 3
```

Comment: I'll test it asap and come back with an answer :) Thanks.